# Get Autodesk Docs local folder using Revit API (or any other method)

Tags: c#, revit-api, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I'm trying to get my Autodesk Docs local folder using C# and Revit API, but I can't find how to do that.

When I am working with a BIM 360 file, using Desktop Connector, it creates the Autodesk Docs folder. But when I try to get the file path using the Document property `PathName` , it returns me something like this:

`Autodesk Docs://XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXX.rvt`

But I need the local path, like:

`C:/Users/MYUSER/ACCDocs/XXXXXXX/XXXXX/..../XXXXX.rvt`

I've already tried to look for the answer on google, here, users groups and nothing, and tried some other ways like using System.IO:

`Directory.GetParent(doc.PathName).FullName`

But it also doesn't work.

Hope you guys can help me with this or at least tell me it's not possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I believe the answer is NO as far as I can tell for any Revit model which is opened from Desktop Connector, the file path is pointing to BIM 360 cloud, but there is no API from Revit which can tell the corresponding local file path. If you know the local folder, maybe you can combine the local folder together with PathName to get the local path.

Edited on Nov 1t:
If the file is Revit Cloud Model, then maybe this blog could give you some idea: https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2021/05/refreshment-cloud-model-path-angle-and-direction.html#3